# HTML Bootstrap Borders/ Panels

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

From this screen grab , I want to have similar borders & background colours on my divs. I'm using Bootstrap framework. Which CSS property or JS library should I use?
[image: screengrab]

Comment: Using a shortened link is against the community policy. Please change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need just css, this is just a sample, but you can do all what you want on style.

```css
.container{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height:200vh;
    
    
    }
 .reset{
    margin:0px !important;
    padding:0px !important;
  }  
       
 .box{
    height:200px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top:10px;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    border-radius:2px;
    }
   
 #box-left{
    margin-right:5px;
    
    }

 #box-left2{
    margin-right:5px;
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row reset">
        <div class="col-xs-8 reset">
            <div id="box-left" class="box">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 reset">
           <div class="box">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row reset">
        <div class="col-xs-2 reset">
            <div id="box-left2" class="box">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 reset">
           <div class="box">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```